# from dataGridView to TextBox, take headername

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, header

I have a question about converting from dataGridView to textbox. I want when see x replace it with the Headername

I have dataGridview here:

```
Name   A    B    C    D    ...
kiki   x         x         ...  
lola        x              ...
maja   x         x    x    ...
```

I want to have in my textbox:

```
kiki A,C    ...
lola B      ...
maja A,C,D  ...
```

My code would look like this i think;

```
string abc = "";
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() != "x")
               abc = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString();               

            richTextBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString() + " " + abc;
            //or something like that, can some1 give me a key?  
        } 
    }
```

Can someone help me with it? don't know how to do it, please give me any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. this code is putting everything into one multiline `richTextBox`and each row is add in a new line:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            string text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString() + " " ;
            bool added = false;
            for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == "x")
                {
                    text += dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString() + ",";
                    if (!added)
                        added = true;
                }
            }
            if(added)
            {
                text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1); //to remove ',' at the end
            }
            richTextBox1.Text += text + Environment.NewLine; //add to richTextbox1 with newline
        }
```

Comment: by the next loop should it be `for(int j=1;j<dataGridView1.COlumns.Count-1; j++)` ? and if should be with == "x"

Comment: @UniLe No problem, again sorry for the bugs.